# Creating thousands of rows in the DB with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot service where we have projects, contributors and a many to many relationship between projects and contributors, this is modeled in JPA as 3 separate entities, Project, Contributor and ProjectContributor. I am using Spring Data to interact with the DB which is in Postgres.

Upon an event consumption from SQS, there are times when we have to create thousands of projects in the DB along with their contributors. These projects and contributors are provided by some external services.

In the scenario where we have to create 1000 projects and each project has an average of 2 contributors, I am making the following calls to the DB through the Spring Data repository save methods for each entity.

1000 calls to ProjectRespository.save() method to create projects

2000 calls to ContributorRespository.save() method to create contributors

2000 calls to ProjectContributorRespository.save() method to associate contributors to projects

And I'm not even counting that before creating a contributor, I have to issue a query to check if the contributor already exists in the DB.

This is all inside a @Transactional method. This logic takes forever to complete, I was wondering what is the best approach to do something like this in Spring Boot and Spring Data to reduce significantly the number of calls to the DB to create the objects mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good fit for batching inserts. Shortly speaking you can perform many inserts in one DB round-trip. Batching is configurable by the property `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`. It is worth noting that batch targets only one table. So 5 inserts to table Project, 5 to Contributor, then once again 5 to Project and 5 to Contributor will be done in 4 batches. Better to do 10 inserts to Project and 10 to Contributor or sort inserts through the property `hibernate.order_inserts`. Then you have only 2 DB round-trips in the aforementioned case. You can read more about it under https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/.